# Site for getting updates on musicians new albums, nearby shows?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for an application that I'm not sure exists.  I want to create a list of current artists that I like.  Then, when those artists have a new album out, or are appearing on TV, or if they have a show near my zipcode, I get sent an email.  Right now I get around this problem by subscribing to each artists mailing list or RSS feed, but this is painful and spotty at best.

Does this app exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't help you with the TV tracking, but [SongKick](http://SongKick.com) does a pretty nice job of tracking when artists are coming near you and notifying you.  It integrates nicely as well with the Events/Concerts tracking in last.fm

The beautiful thing about last.fm events is it will also give you a recommendation feed of shows you may enjoy based on stuff you are listening to (scrobbling)

Some other options (although SongKick + Last.fm events is my preferred method):

- [BandsInTown](http://www.bandsintown.com/home)
- [TourFilter](http://tourfilter.com)
- [SonicLiving](http://sonicliving.com)

Answer (score 0):

[Last.fm](http://last.fm) used to do these kind of stuff I think.

Comment: The $3/month fee is just for radio access outside of US, UK & Germany.  Otherwise all other functionality is free

Comment: @3rdparty that's exactly what I said.. but it's not just for the outside.. US, UK & Germany is a smaller portion of the world.. :P

Comment: no, you implied it's $3/month outside of those 3 countries to use the site at all - what I was clearing up is that only the radio function requires the $3/month fee, all other features/services (including concert/event tracker) are free no matter where you are located.

Comment: @3rdparty aha.. I didn't know that :) So I can just remove that part for this answer.. :D

Answer (score 0):

[Purevolume](http://purevolume.com) is intended for this, although for the most part it only caught on with alternative and indie rock bands.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/XML_Web_Service).

Comment: That's interesting.  I don't see anywhere that it lets you keep alerts set up on certain bands but it is still good to know that site exists.