# New Releases from favourite artists?

Tags: music

Is there a web app that simply notifies me when the artists I like (eg through last.fm) release something new?

I'm struggling to find an easy way to keep up with new music...

Comment: Closely related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/site-for-getting-updates-on-musicians-new-albums-nearby-shows

Answer (score 5):

[Album Reminder](http://www.albumreminder.com/features) will do this for you. It can read your favorite artists from iTunes or last.fm, or you can just enter them manually. Then it'll send you an email when one of those tracked artists releases something new. Or, if you prefer, you can subscribe to an RSS feed of reminders about those artists.

Answer (score -1):

You could use this http://www.billboard.com/new-releases
or
http://www.music-alerts.com/ they use rss
or
try this website  newalbumreleases.net
or
u could use the nomis app for iphone
or
www.feedrevolution.com/  this is powered by last.fm and they will notify you via email!!